# Does aging as a dragon PC give ability score increases?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ability-scores, dragons, aging

When a dragon PC ages does it work like getting a paragon class that stacks with sorcerer levels? For example when a brown dragon advances from wyrmling to very young, its strength increases by 4 and its constitution increases by 2. Would a player character get +4 strength and +2 constitution upon aging?

Comment: Are you using a specific source for dragon PCs, or just the basic Monster Manual rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Draconomicon*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786928840) includes information for dragon player-characters—like aging effects—on pages 141–4. Such rules are too extensive to reproduce here, but, in short, "When a dragon reaches a new age category, its ability scores improve across the board," but, as "it ages… the dragon is required to devote a level every few years to its dragon 'class,' reflecting the extra Hit Die or level adjustment it gains from aging." *Draconomicon* mentions on page 144 how to determine what the game thinks is an appropriate level adjustment for an aging brown dragon (*Monstrous Compendium: Monsters of Faerûn* 38–40).

So, yes, as dragons age, their ability scores increase, but the game believes such ability score increases shouldn't come free.